# iOS StatusBar color change animation

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

I use the following code to change the StatusBar color in my `ViewController`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.default
}
```

And the parameter `View controller-based status bar appearance` in `info.plist` is set to NO

But the problem is that the StatusBar color changes from black to white without animation, and I want to make smooth transition between these states. Any ideas?

Xcode 10 Beta 5, iOS 12 Dev Beta 6

Comment: Why not you try the propertyAnimator.
I think it'll work for you.

Comment: I think you have to use `View controller-based status bar appearance = YES` to use animation, because `UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarStyle` is deprecated. Maybe try wrap it inside animation block and check?

Comment: For propertyAnimator follow this https://medium.com/swift-and-ios-writing/a-quick-look-at-uiviewpropertyanimator-a107fb9da5b5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set following for one VC

```
 override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
```

and then set the other as below

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.default
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I replaced my code with yours and the StatusBar started changing color with animation, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle
override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation
```

It's required to call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` whenever you want this transition to get happened (Mostly in **viewWillAppear**)